# Is there a way to open mailto: and tel: links from a service worker?

Tags: javascript, push-notification, service-worker

I'm using push notifications handled from a service worker.

The main motivation to use notifications was to provide actions as "Call to" or "Mail to", I though that the behaviour would be the same as clicking on a "mailto:" link.

It works using chrome on windows (launches mail app on click for example) but fails using chrome on android, resulting in a black tab with the url "mailto:..." written on it.

```
// Service Worker
self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function(event) {
  const { contactRequest } = JSON.parse(event.notification.data);
  switch(event.action) {
    case 'call':
      return clients.openWindow('tel:' + contactRequest.phone);
    case 'mail':
      return clients.openWindow('mailto:' + contactRequest.email);
  }
});
```

Comment: Shouldn't it just be `mailto:` without the slashes?

Comment: The original code was without slashes. I saw them somewhere and gave them a try. Didn't notice I wrote the snippet with slashes, but neither works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Updated with additional information*

This seems to be a bug that manifests itself in many ways - Claimed to be fixed here for an unrelated origin - https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=792990

There are not many options within the notification feature itself, you can only use a `openWindow` which creates or uses a window to perform additional options.

The issue faced in Chrome is acknowledged in MDN  as well -https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clients/openWindow

There are two approaches here

1. Open or focus your application and add a `hash` which servers as a marker that the notification was clicked - this lets you add a target `_top` or `_blank`

*Pseudo code with credit to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clients/openWindow)*

```
// Notification click event listener
self.addEventListener('notificationclick', e => {
  // Close the notification popout
  e.notification.close();
  // Get all the Window clients
  e.waitUntil(clients.matchAll({ type: 'window' }).then(clientsArr => {
    // If a Window tab matching the targeted URL already exists, add a "#mailNotification"
    const hadWindowToFocus = clientsArr.some(windowClient => windowClient.url === e.notification.data.url ? (windowClient.navigate(e.notification.data.url+"#mailNotification").then(function(client){client.focus()}), true) : false);

// Add additional code to add a 
    // Otherwise, open a new tab to the applicable URL and focus it.
    if (!hadWindowToFocus) clients.openWindow(e.notification.data.url+"#mailNotification").then(windowClient => windowClient ? 
    windowClient.navigate(e.notification.data.url+"#mailNotification").then(function(client){client.focus()})
     : null);
  }));

// Then in your page, you can just use window.onhashChange event
window.onhashchange = weFixChromeLinks



function weFixChromeLinks () {

// ... Create an anchor tag that is formatted to your mailto has a target _top or _blank, hide the link and dispatch a click.
}
```

2. *Earlier Approach*

Since the `clients.openWindow` method does not supply ability to target the `_top` window, you might have to set an intermediary page that supports a `_top` - i.e

```
// Your intermediate page 
window.open('mailto...','_top')
```

**Closing words**
The issue itself is *ugly* - Browsers are supposed to know intents, e.g: Apps, mail programs etc. - It seems like Chrome for android treats it like another URL and fails miserably.

Comment: As I said in the comments I was using mailto: without slashes from the start (I'll update the question so it doesn't create more confusion). Create a page only to call window.open was one of my options, discarded later because it's an ugly workaround.

Comment: Doesn't really solve my problem, but if there is no way to do it like I want there is nothing more to do. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Thank you for the bounty made my day :)